# Install New Hard Drive and Dual Boot Win 7 and Win 8

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I have a Lenovo H430 desktop that has a single hard drive with Windows 7 installed. Here's what I want to do:

1. Install a SSD drive and install Windows 8 on the SSD.
2. Dual boot Windows 7 and Windows 8.

How would I go about doing this? Do I need to change the active partitions or do anything so that the dual boot menu shows up? I haven't done this before.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is install Windows 8 on the SSD. It should detect the existing boot manager on the other drive and add its own entries to it (it might actually upgrade it as well). At least that's how older setups worked. I'm not really sure on the Windows 8 one though (but I'd assume it's the same).

Comment: You are correct about upgrading the boot manager, see step 3...http://lifehacker.com/5840387/how-to-dual+boot-windows-7-and-windows-8-side-by-side

Comment: Ah right, the graphical thingy - I've read about it. I quite like it, but I'm still not sure whether to do the system upgrade.